# Show all error messages in one place in one page checkout

Tags: magento2, javascript, onepage-checkout, knockout

I want to show validation messages in one place.

for example.

```html
<div class="checkout-error-message">
* Please fill address field
* Please fill email field
* Please check agreement and term
</div>
```

But, I couldn't find out how to do this. 
What should I do for it?
Thanks.